# OpenCart. Credit card payment platform in Spain

Tags: methods, opencart, payment, credit-card

I’m brand new for online stores programming and have a simple question. What is the most used credit card payment plugin for OpenCart, I don't care if is free or not, but what I appreciate is very low commissions on purchases.
Thanks.

Comment: Depends on your country. In what country are you going to receive payments?

Comment: The payments will be in Spain!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Stripe](https://stripe.com/)

One of the best platform for running an credit card payments.

And the OpenCart modules for Stripe:

https://stripe.com/partners/opencart-stripe-payment-gateway

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_search=Stripe